# Convert iPad app using Storyboard into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

I have one view which was created for iPad, using a Storyboard.

Now, I want to convert it to an iPhone app.

I am very new to Storyboards. Until now, I have been using separate XIB files.

Can you please explain to me the steps for doing this?

Comment: "I amusing separate xib files." - I thought XIB files were boring...

Comment: ya...it may be..As fresher , I have started with xibs.Can you tell me the solution?

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, but no. I don't use Interface Builder.

Comment: YEs you have to create two diffrent xib's and present it according to the device.

Comment: ya but how can i add iphone view in storyboard? I am having 0 knowledge in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is important, if you want your app to just run on both iphone and ipad, you can go to project Summary and then in devices select "Universal" option. This will just run your app in both iphone and ipad(full screen and not 2x). But if you want to look it better then you have to manage your UI assets accordingly.

Comment: The question is about converting ipad to iphone , not iphone to ipad

Comment: Ya..That i know.But storyboard is new for me..So How can I create iphone view in storyboard?

Comment: ya...app is already done by someone in ipad.I need to convert all the views in iphone.all fuctionalities should work in same manner for iphone

Comment: @KingofBliss, but the problem remains same in both the cases

Comment: @khushbu, create xibs for iphone separately

Comment: please tell me how can I add those xibs in storyboad? I am having no idea about storyboard sir.

Comment: go to add new file by clicking on the project then select userinterface->storyboard->iphone

Comment: see i am having 1 storyboard name mainstoryboard.storyboard .all xibs in ipad Now can I add 1 other iphone view in that mainstoryboard?